What is the metric used to eliminate states in $jj$ coupling for equivalent electron atoms?
Consider the example of an np$^2$ atom - both $l$ and $s$ are equal, which leads to equal j values. However, when considering J, some values get eliminated. How is this determined?
I understand that there is a link between symmetric and anti-symmetric states when considering S and L, and forming pairs for that, but what is the explanation behind it?
